# Storing private keys in keystore in Android

Tags: android, android-keystore

I need to store some private user's values in SharedPreferences.

I came across this article:
https://medium.com/@ericfu/securely-storing-secrets-in-an-android-application-501f030ae5a3

It explains most of the things you have to do, but it seems to be missing the part about how to save the private and public key (for API<23) into the keystore.

So if we have API version 18-22 we do the following:
we open a keystore

```
KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(AndroidKeyStore);
keyStore.load(null);
```

we generate the key pair

```
Calendar start = Calendar.getInstance();
Calendar end = Calendar.getInstance();
end.add(Calendar.YEAR, 30);

KeyPairGeneratorSpec spec = new KeyPairGeneratorSpec.Builder(mContext)
                                .setAlias(KEY_ALIAS)
                                .setSubject(new X500Principal("CN=" + KEY_ALIAS))
                                .setSerialNumber(BigInteger.TEN)
                                .setStartDate(start.getTime())
                                .setEndDate(end.getTime())
                                .build();
KeyPairGenerator kpg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance(KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_RSA, AndroidKeyStore);
kpg.initialize(spec);
mEncryptionPair = kpg.generateKeyPair();
```

Now we can use public key for encrypting data and private key to decrypt it. But we need to save the keypair to the keystore and later retrieve it. 
How do I do this exactly?

I am also concerned about why Android Studio displays a warning for this line

```
KeyPairGenerator kpg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance(KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_RSA, AndroidKeyStore);
```

the warning:

```
Field requires API level 23 (current min is 14): android.security.keystore.KeyProperties#KEY_ALGORITHM_RSA
```

Answer (score 1):

I know, this question is too old, but i had the same problem. Here is the solution if someone needs

```
     if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                  spec = new KeyPairGeneratorSpec.Builder(mContext)
                        .setAlias(alias)
                        .setSubject(new X500Principal("CN=" + alias))
                        .setSerialNumber(BigInteger.valueOf(1337))
                        .setStartDate(start.getTime())
                        .setEndDate(end.getTime())
                        .build();
            } else {
                spec = new KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder(alias, KeyProperties.PURPOSE_SIGN)
                        .setCertificateSubject(new X500Principal("CN=" + alias))
                        .setDigests(KeyProperties.DIGEST_SHA256)
                        .setSignaturePaddings(KeyProperties.SIGNATURE_PADDING_RSA_PKCS1)
                        .setCertificateSerialNumber(BigInteger.valueOf(1337))
                        .setCertificateNotBefore(start.getTime())
                        .setCertificateNotAfter(end.getTime())
                        .build();
            }
```